# Jinja2 list is undefined

Tags: python, list, jinja2

In Jinja2 I want to print the length of the 'first' value in a dictionary. In Python this would be done with the command `len(list(my_dict.values())[0])`.

When I try this in Jinja2 I get the error `jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'list' is undefined`.

Minimum working example:

```
from jinja2 import Template, DebugUndefined
from shutil import copyfile


def main(file_name_template, file_name_log):

    # Copy template file 'file_name_template' to 'file_name_log' so that logging can start.
    copyfile(file_name_template, file_name_log)
    template = Template(open(file_name_log).read(), undefined=DebugUndefined)

    # Define test variable 'my_dict'.
    my_dict = {'key_0': 4641896,
               'key_1': 189478415,
               'key_2': 841653}

    # Start logging.
    template_render_dict = {'my_dict': my_dict}

    # Save log to external file and possibly open upon completion of the 'main' program.
    template_rendered = template.render(template_render_dict)  # Render the template to the filled in log report.


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main("template.html", "template_rendered.html")
```

with in `template.html` the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        {{my_dict}}<br/>
        {{my_dict.keys()}}<br/>
        {{my_dict.values()}}<br/>
        {{len(list(my_dict.values())[0])}}<br/>
    </body>
</html>
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use Python `list` in jinja2 template because it's not Python, it is a mark language. However, it provides a [`length`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#length) method. Instead of:

```
{% if len(dict.values()[0]) > 1 %}
```

You should write:

```
{% if dict.values()[0] | length > 1 %}

# or
{% if dict.values() | first | length > 1 %}
```

Please see doc for more examples.

Comment: Don't you mean I should use `{{my_dict.values() | first | length}}` instead of `{{len(list(my_dict.values())[0])}}`? This indeed works, so thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Adriaan you can upvote or accept the answer, I'll be appreciate.

Comment: I got this error because my template had dashes in one of the variable names